# Full Bash script on creating txt file, directory, copy file, display info

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting, raspberry-pi, file-copy

Im still very new to codeing and Im still learning the basics and would love some help with explanation to learn what to do. Im stuck on this matter atm:
Bash script to create a file with text inside and then create a new directory on /home, then copy the file and change the name into the /home/newdirectory text inside file, displaying all files thats on /home.

this is what i got atm:

```
#!/bin/bash
touch textfile
mv textfile txtfile
mkdir testdir
cp txtfile testdir
cat txtfile
```

Comment: Split the problem down. How do you write out text (to the screen)? How do you then write that text into a file? Get this part 1 sorted then move on. Don't try to deliver the whole thing in one go

Comment: so like:  'touch testfile "any text" > testfile'

Comment: Ah. The `touch` command is intended for resetting file status times. Your command will have created two files `testfile` and `any text`. You probably want something like  `echo "hello, world" >testfile`. Maybe it's time to refresh yourself with your teacher's notes?

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure if I got your point. Do you want something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir -p $HOME/newdirectory
ls $HOME > $HOME/newdirectory/ls_home.txt
```

Comment: yes i do believe its something like this. But instead of directly creating the file with whats on my home page into the directory. Its more like creating the file that shows my home page info, then creating a directory. Then copying that file into that new directory. And all of this should be a single script aswell. If that makes sense?